# Is it possible to write a serialized object (in String) into the user meta data using AmazonS3?

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-flink, minio

I've a flink job that consumes kafka content and writes it into a minio via AmazonS3 api.

I've encountered error 400 bad header request if I attempt to copy a string output of a serialized object.

Is there any work-around if I need to save the serialized object into the user metadata of the object?

edit: I decided to 64bit encode the content; that works fine with the metadata.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can save strings in user metadata, however there are encoding considerations - most browsers and clients only consistently support US-ASCII, and there are size restrictions - [user metadata is limited to 2KB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/UsingMetadata.html).

Please know you can find us at https://slack.min.io/ 24/7/365. If you have commercial questions, please reach out to us on hello@min.io or on our Ask an Expert Chat functionality at https://min.io/pricing?action=talk-to-us.